# Applying map function on an array after filter

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, filter, angularjs

In my html (.ng-template) I have an array, on which a filter is applied. I want to apply a map function to the result of this filter function (It's too expensive to apply it to the whole array before applying the filter). The older versions of `angularjs` allowed me to do so by

```
<ng-repeat = 'item in array.$filter(filterFunc).map(mapFunc).$orderBy("orderFunc()")'>
```

But with the new syntax (v 1.0.5) I am not able to do this.

```
<ng-repeat = 'item in array|filter:filterFunc|orderBy:"orderFunc()"'>
```

I do don't understand how do I apply map function to this. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are hard to test, do not write any business logic in the templates, besides, these functions will create a new copy of your array and apply map function *every time* in every `$digest` phase.

You should do this in your controller and use `ngRepeat` within that.

```
function MyCtrl ($scope, $filter) {
  var fullArray = [1,2,3];
  var otherArray = $filter(filterFunc).map(mapFunc);
}
```

.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in otherArray | orderBy:orderFn"></div>
```

You can also order the array in the controller.

Comment: Strangely, I had the same solution, and I actually was trying to move that logic in the template.....sleepy idiot of me!